# Python IDLE Traceback error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn Python on my own. I created a Python file to to print Hello, world! My Python file (called test), which I did not save in the IDLE or Python library, is:

```
def hello():                                             
    print "Hello,world!"
```

When I ran this file in the Python shell as hello(),the error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
hello
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

Can you help me troubleshoot the cause of this problem?

Comment: post the full code..

Comment: I was mirroring a sample code I found on an online CS site and this was the only code given. It would print like this in the Python Shell (according to their images): Hello,world! after hello() was called. I'm extremely confused now haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your full code is something like this:

```
hello() # this hasn't been defined yet

def hello():
    println "Hello, world!"
```

When you call `hello()` on line 1, the function has not been defined yet because Python executes that script from the start to the end. Move the function call below the function:

```
def hello():
    println "Hello, world!"

hello() # now Python knows what hello is
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried that and it still gives the same error. I'm thinking it may have something to do with my file not actually saving as a .py file when I save it. For some reason the file type is simply "File." Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you post the entire file you tried to run? That would be extremely helpful.

Comment: How are you running the program? You should either run the .py file from Python's IDLE or run it with the python <filename> command.